# Make Vista+ file dialogs work before main form is created

Tags: delphi, com, delphi-2007, fileopendialog

In a little app I want to show a open file dialog before the main form is created. I do it like this in the *.dpr:

```
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Init; // <=========================================
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

When I use the following Init procedure:

```
procedure Init;
var
  OpenDialog: TOpenDialog;
begin
  TheFileName := '(nix)';

  OpenDialog := TOpenDialog.Create(nil);
  try
    if OpenDialog.Execute then
      TheFileName := OpenDialog.FileName
    else
      Exit;
  finally
    OpenDialog.Free;
  end;
end;
```

there is no dialog shown under Windows 7. I can fix this by setting UseLatestCommonDialogs to False but I'd like to avoid that. Changing the Init procedure to

```
procedure Init;
var
  OpenDialog: TOpenDialog;
begin
  TheFileName := '(nix)';

  CoInitialize(nil);
  try
    OpenDialog := TOpenDialog.Create(nil);
    try
      if OpenDialog.Execute then
        TheFileName := OpenDialog.FileName
      else
        Exit;
    finally
      OpenDialog.Free;
    end;
  finally
    CoUninitialize;
  end;
end;
```

works. However I'm not sure If I got the CoInitialize/CoUninitialize right, e.g.:

- Do I mess something up by calling CoUninitialize so early?
- Having to "know" the fact that TOpenDialog internally (sometimes) uses COM smells like leaky abstraction that I'd rather avoid.

**Edit:** I found a slightly better way: If I add `ComObj` to the dpr's `uses` clause I can omit the `CoInitialize`/`CoUninitialize` calls. The leaky abstraction issue stills holds, of course.

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you describe. It also does not ring true because `CoInitialize` is  called in `Application.Initialize`.

Comment: I would have thought so too. But the facts are different. :-)

Comment: FWIW: InitProc is nil inside the call to `Application.Initialize`.

Comment: ... unless I use `ComObj` - see edit.

Comment: See [`documentation`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TApplication_Initialize.html). "`In Delphi, you can include a unit that assigns a procedure to InitProc in its initialization section, such as the ComObj unit.`"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the issue is that COM is not being initialized. This normally happens in `Application.Initialize` because of the initialization procedure that is added by using `ComObj`. But you report in a comment that `InitProc` is `nil` inside `Application.Initialize` which indicates that `ComObj` is not included in your project.

So, you can solve the issue readily by including `ComObj` in your project. Or if you want to be explicit about it, just call `CoInitilize(nil)` at the very start of your .dpr file.

Comment: That's what I'll do for now. Out of curiosity: You don't have to do that on your system? Do you use D2007? Emba probably fixed Dialogs.pas to set up all requirements by itself after D2007.